# WideCharToMultiByte not converting Japanese on English OS

Tags: c++, stdstring, unicode-string, widechar

I need to convert file names from `System.String` into `std::string`. I am using both Japanese and English file names.

For English file names, there is no issue.

Only Japanese file names are not converting to `std::string` in English Windows 10.

I used `WideCharToMultiByte()` and code page 932.

```
std::string marshal_as(System::String^ str)
{
    std::string convertedstring;
    size_t _size = 0;
    cli::pin_ptr<const wchar_t> _pinned_ptr = PtrToStringChars(str);
    _size = WideCharToMultiByte(932, 0, _pinned_ptr, str->Length, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (_size > 0)
    {
        convertedstring.resize(_size);
        char* buffer = &convertedstring[0];
        WideCharToMultiByte(932, 0, _pinned_ptr, -1, &buffer[0], _size, 0, 0);

    }

    return convertedstring;
}
```

Here `str` is `"C:\\files\\ブ種別.pdf"`

`convertedstring` is `"C:\\files\\ƒuŽí•Ê.pdf"`

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Please post your code, see [mre].

Comment: posted the code which i used

Comment: Do you have Windows or IBM?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932_(Microsoft_Windows)

Comment: Please be more descriptive of what "not converting" means. Are they removed from the output? Are they copied unchanged? Are they converted to U+FFFD (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER)? Does WideCharToMultiByte report zero characters converted?

Comment: @jdweng I am using Windows

Comment: @RaymondChen sorry.. now I added the japanese string and converted string

Comment: Do you terminate the string with '\0'.  What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any specific error. Instead of japanese string i am getting junk characters.

Comment: How are you using the returned string? Is the code that uses it [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1010785/11683) that it's in codepage 932?

Comment: The string is converted correctly. The character ブ is represented by the bytes 0x83 0x75 in code page 932. The problem is that you are printing it in code page 1252, not 932. In code page 1252, the byte 0x83 is the character "ƒ" and the byte 0x75 is the character "u". (Also, I removed the C# tag from this question seeing as there's no C# in it.)

Comment: If you convert a string to code page 932, then the only place it makes sense is in code page 932.

Comment: is it not possible to do in English OS?

Comment: @GSerg  returned string will be passed to cpp library

Comment: @Saya You are having the **exact same issue** that [you asked about yesterday with different code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62413509/). You are *converting* your Japanese strings to `std::string` correctly, but whatever is *using* those converted strings afterwards is not *interpreting* the strings correctly, so you are not getting the results you want. Your conversions themselves are fine.

Comment: thank you for your help.Now I understood what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is fixed.I enabled Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support option in region settings in control panel.